# Typescript: Import namespace when namespace and class have the same name in a library file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, golden-layout

I am having issue with accessing namespace while importing it from a file that declares the namespace and a class with the same name. I can access the class but not the namespace.

From the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), I thought importing from a library that exports merged namespace and class will give you properties from both declarations. But, I am getting properties from the class only.

> Namespaces are flexible enough to also merge with other types of
>   declarations. To do so, the namespace declaration must follow the
>   declaration it will merge with. The resulting declaration has
>   properties of both declaration types. TypeScript uses this capability
>   to model some of the patterns in JavaScript as well as other
>   programming languages.

Here is my scenario,

Library file:

```
class GoldenLayout {
}

namespace GoldenLayout {
    export interface Config {
    }
}
```

In my project, I am trying to use `Config` interface. I am trying to use it this way,

```
import * as GoldenLayout from 'golden-layout';

const INITIAL_LAYOUT = GoldenLayout.Config = {
};
```

However, I get an error

```
Property 'Config' does not exist on type 'typeof GoldenLayout'.
```

I can access properties and method in the class GolderLayour, but I don't know how I can access the namespace.

For Reference, I am trying to use this [library](https://github.com/golden-layout/golden-layout) in my Angular 8 app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is that your not defining Config but rather double assigning. Try this:

```
const INITIAL_LAYOUT: GoldenLayout.Config = { };
```

Comment: How stupid of me to not notice that. Thank you so much.